# Can I convert a modifier modified object to a simple object?

Tags: particles, hair

I am desperately trying to use a hair modifier around a sphere to grow hairs that are based on a specified object. I would like this to be a pre-generated 3D curve that I have hair modified BUT this is not working.  Only the curve itself (not with its modified "hairs") is being grown from the sphere.  I hope this makes sense and apologies of this is a dumb question.  any help hugely appreciated

Comment: if you can share a screenshot to better understand what you're trying to achieve, maybe it could help.

Comment: Hi...in essence I want the grown hairs to be objects that I have pre-made within another collection from a particle modifier.  I can select the latter and select "convert particles to mesh" and then use that as the object but that actually doesn't work (the hairs grown in the secondary particle modification dont render)

Comment: The problem is highlighted here but I am not keen on their workaround: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKIaXCmvJo

Comment: There are several ways to grow hair, but I don't know what you mean by pregenerated curve, that's why I asked you for a screenshot. But if you can share your project it would be much better.

Comment: Hi, many thanks again, I appreciate it.  No doubt I am being dumb but I can't see how I upload a screenshot.  the only option I have is "add a comment".

Comment: I start like this.  I have a new 3D noise curve and hair modify this to generate a "functionalism hair".  I then want to grow this "functionalism hair" from another object.  That's basically it.   Ideally I would be able to convert the initially modified hair into a simple object but that simply doesn't seem to be an option